# Serialization and Deserialization of private fields

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I have a class in which I have defined all instance variables as private. I don't have getters and setters for all the fields. Now if I have such object after desrialization then how can i access the private instance variables.

Comment: Why do you want to access `private` values? And what differences does it make that the object was created by deserialization?

Answer (score 2):

You can access them the same way as before: Only inside the instance that is declaring the fields.(*) Nothing changes after serialization and deserialization.

(*) And of course via reflection as you could before.